# How can i check if no arguments are given

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I want to check if the user has given the script any arguments and if this is the case, the script should close.

```
if [ $@ = "" ]; then
    exit
fi
```

is not working.

Comment: The number of arguments are stored in the variable `$#`

Comment: Note, the reason this doesn't work, is that you need to put double quotes around `$@` because of how bash handles empty strings. Unquoted, the first line becomes `if [ = "" ]; then` when no arguments are passed in, which results in a syntax error. Quoted, you have `if [ "" = "" ]; then`, which is treated as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
fi
```